# python seperating values

Tags: python

I am getting a response like this `id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8` and I want to define the value of the `id` and the value of the `code` in separate strings
How can I do this in python selenium maybe with regex(which I don't completely understand it)?

Comment: like value of the id which is [51555263943] and value of the code which is [q15cd225s6s8] and would be like this [respose_id = '51555263943']

Comment: thanks for the tip it has been a while since my last activity on SO almost forgot the ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the response on the '&' value and assign the returned list elements to new variables.

```
input = 'id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8'.split('&')

id = input[0].split('=')[1]

code = input[1].split('=')[1]

print(id)
print(code)
```

Output:

```
51555263943 
q15cd225s6s8
```

Comment: i want only the values

Comment: oh and one thing the response im getting is already defined as [result] I can use like this? [input = result.split('&')] or ?

Comment: What is the exact string you need to extract the id and code from? ```result = 'id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8'```?

Comment: result = solver.turnstile(
           sitekey='API_KEY',
           url='https://www.website.com/',
       )

    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(e)

    else:
        print('result: ' + str(result))

Comment: and result is id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The solution already extracts the id and code values from ```id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252955/discussion-between-catchmeifucan-and-captain-caveman).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the strings always come like that and that you are using regex:

```
import re
s = 'id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8'
output = re.findall(r'(?<=\=)[^&]+',s,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

*output* is a list containing the id and the code you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would also use the split method to create a list based on "&".
Afterwards I would loop over the list and do a split on "=" and store these values in a dictionary, so they are easy to access later. This way you can also easily scale to a bigger response.

```
res = 'id=51555263943&code=q15cd225s6s8'
resSplit = res.split('&')

resDict = {}

for i in resSplit:
  i_split = i.split('=')
  resDict[i_split[0]] = i_split[1]

print(resDict)
>>>> output
{'id': '51555263943', 'code': 'q15cd225s6s8'}
```